# Split colon-separated strings in a column into different columns in R

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c('0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28', '0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30', '0/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16'))

data

                                    col1
1 0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28
2 0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30
3   1/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16
```

I want to extract the number before the second colon, namely `0/1`, `0/1`, `1/1`, `60,4`, `58,4`, `25,2`, and split it into different columns.

```
data
                                    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    
1 0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28       0       1      60       4
2 0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30       0       1      58       4
3   1/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16       1       1      25       2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strsplit` twice (once with `:`, again with `[/,]`) and `[`-extraction works like this:

```r
tmp <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(strsplit(data$col1, ":"), function(st) as.integer(unlist(strsplit(st, "[/,]")[1:2]))))
cbind(data, setNames(tmp, paste0("col", 1+seq_len(ncol(tmp)))))
#                                     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
# 1 0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28    0    1   60    4
# 2 0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30    0    1   58    4
# 3   0/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16    0    1   25    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dplyr solution with `strsplit` and `separate`

```
data %>% 
  mutate(col2 = strsplit(sub('(^[^:]+:[^:]+):(.*)$', '\\1 \\2', col1), ' ')) %>% 
  separate(col2, c("col2", NA), sep = " ") %>% 
  separate(col2, c(NA, "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"), extra = "drop", fill = "right")
```

Output:

```
                                    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1 0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28    0    1   60    4
2 0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30    0    1   58    4
3   0/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16    0    1   25    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `read.csv` after extracting the substring in `base R`

```
data[paste0('col', 2:5)] <- read.csv(text = gsub("[[:punct:]]", ",", 
    sub('^([^,]+,\\d+):.*', "\\1", data$col1)), header = FALSE)
```

-output

```
data
#                                    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
#1 0/1:60,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28    0    1   60    4
#2 0/1:58,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30    0    1   58    4
#3   0/1:25,2:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16    0    1   25    2
```